# How to show a query has been processed in an asp:UpdatePanel if the data doesn't change

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have some controls inside an asp:UpdatePanel. When a button is pressed to update the repeater data the data may change but it might not though. If the data doesn't change it's hard to tell if you pressed the button or not.

Can someone explain to me how you would add some sort of image or progress bar over the top of the panel to show when processing of the data is happening?

This way at least the user should know that their request has been acknowledged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UpgadeProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) control was designed to provide feedback to the user that an async request is occurring.  This is the simplest way to accomplish this.

You can also wire into the ScriptManager's pageLoaded event if you want to do something more custom after the response is received.  A good tutorial can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398866.aspx

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer and the tutorial! Works really well!